# Encoding URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am stuck with the problem at java script side

1)

```
var text='{"type": "comTocomp","data":[{ "1" : "Key Parameters" , "2" : "Steel - Sponge/ Pig Iron"},   
          { "1" : "No of Companies" , "2" : "6,6 %  "  }]}';
```

This is my var text i want to send it server side for generating the excel sheet
and also the browser should prompt with popup as to save the file for this i am doing

2)

```
       var url="/XXX/YYYY/genrateSheet";       // URL OF CONTROLLER
       var encode=url+ "?data="+text;          // URL + PARAMETER+ TEXT CONTENT 
        var resUri=encodeURIComponent(encode); // TRIED TO ENCODE BUT DOESN'T WORK
        **window.location.replace(resUri);**       // CALLING TO CONTROLLER TO PROMPT POPUP
```

The problem is as in **var text** if it content some special character  like **% , .** the browser shows

```
 The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared
```

But none of the special character then works fine for me.

I have Google a lot but want to encode the **url** with the use **window.location.replace(resUri)**

any help would be help me a lot.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @fge yeh right by mistake.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the value of the querystring not the querystring itself:

```
var url="/XXX/YYYY/genrateSheet";       // URL OF CONTROLLER
var resUri = url + "?data=" + encodeURIComponent(text); // querystring
window.location.replace(resUri);
```

Saying that, `text` is quite long, so you should consider `post`ing it to the new page, instead of passing it in the URL. One way to do that using jquery is to create and submit a hidden form containing the data you want:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

    var text='{"type": "comTocomp","data":[{ "1" : "Key Parameters" , "2" : "Steel - Sponge/ Pig Iron"}, { "1" : "No of Companies" , "2" : "6,6 %  "  }]}';

    // create a hidden form    
    var theForm = $('<form action="/XXX/YYYY/genrateSheet" method="post"/>').hide();

    // create a textarea named data and set your json inside it
    var theTextarea = $('<textarea name="data"/>').val(text); // data in your case

    // add the textarea to the form
    theForm.append(theTextarea);

    // submit the form
    theForm.submit();
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utpckatn/1/)

Comment: @Anurag I have updated my answer to show one way to post the data

Comment: actually my text data is very long in that case at server side it shows "Error parsing HTTP request header"... wat should i do now

Comment: with the use window.location.replace it is unsuccess full